# How to get the average of x data in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba, average

I am doing an average of data (VBA Excel) as below:

```
    If n < 8 Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 20).Value = "=SUM(E" & i & ":S" & i & ")/" & n
    Else
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 20).Value = "=AVERAGE(LARGE(E" & i & ":S" & i & ", {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))"
    End If
    n = 0
```

This code is working, because I want the best 8 values of 15 values.
My question is how to do the same with x values (x will be introduced via a userform, `0<x<16`).
Of course, I could use a Select Case with 15 lines depending of x, but it does not seem to me a good coding.

Any ideas?

Comment: My last sentence has been cut. Don't know why? Then, to finish it: x is between 0 and 16 not included. I would like to introduce x via a userform to have the choice. Of course, I could use a Select Case with 15 lines, but I don't think it is a good coding. Any ideas? Note: I didn't do the edit on the main text of my question because the original text is there! Sorry, it appears to be there now and I can't get rid off this comment.

Comment: Is there an `AVERAGEIF` formula in your excel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AVERAGEIF` is available:

```
Sheet2.Cells(i, 20).Value = "=AVERAGEIF(E" & i & ":S" & i & ","">=""&LARGE(E" & i & ":S" & i & "," & x & "))"
```

For i = 2 and x = 8, the formula is:`=AVERAGEIF(E2:S2,">="&LARGE(E2:S2,8))`

If not:

```
Sheet2.Cells(i, 20).Value = "=SUMIF(E" & i & ":S" & i & ","">=""&LARGE(E" & i & ":S" & i & "," & x & "))/" & x
```

For i = 2 and x = 8, the formula is:`=SUMIF(E2:S2,">="&LARGE(E2:S2,8))/8`

Comment: Thanks (with AVERAGEIF). It took me a bit of time to understand, but it is working fine.

Comment: I found out that it could be wrong when there are more than 2 or more values the same as the xth. However if the values are identical, it still returns the result you desired.

Comment: Thanks for this extra comments. However, it is unlikely to have the same value in my case.